# Can not open file "fltkd.lib" error in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, fltk

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>

int main()
{
    FI_Window window(200, 200, "Window title"); // error: FI
    FL_Box box(0, 0, 200, 200, "Hey, I mean, Hello, World! ");
    window.show();
    return Fl::run();
}
```

I build the above code in VS 2019 and and get an error code **LNK1104 | Can not open file "fltkd.lib"**. I have all the linker settings/values checked as suggested in the book Programming Principles and Practices using C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup and other online sources  but still I am getting the error. Is there some different settings with VS 2019 or am I putting the libs file in the wrong directries.

Directory where I put the libs files:-

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\lib

Comment: Add that path to Properties/Configuration Properties/Linker/General/Additional Library Directories,

Comment: @cup I did that and now I am getting the error LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library

Comment: Check the C++ code generation options.  You have a choice of 4 but for debug purposes choose either multithreaded debug or multithreaded debug DLL.  This really depends on how the fltk debug library was built.  You need to choose the same option.  If you don't know how it was built, then you have to try each one of the code generation options in turn.  The alternative is to add msvcrtd to the ignore list but that is never a good option

Comment: @cup It's solved! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library

If you compiled one file to use one kind of run-time library and another file to use another kind (for example, debug versus retail) and tried to link them, you will get this warning. You should compile all source files to use the same run-time library.

`Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library`

There are 4 versions of the CRT link libraries present in vc\lib:

libcmt.lib: static CRT link library for a release build (/MT)

libcmtd.lib: static CRT link library for a debug build (/MTd)

msvcrt.lib: import library for the release DLL version of the CRT (/MD)

msvcrtd.lib: import library for the debug DLL version of the CRT (/MDd)

According to the Doc:[Linker Tools Warning LNK4098](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-warning-lnk4098?view=msvc-160)

when your executable uses the multi-threaded, non-debug run-time libraries, the list reported should include LIBCMT.lib, and not LIBCMTD.lib, MSVCRT.lib, or MSVCRTD.lib. You can tell the linker to ignore the incorrect run-time libraries by using [/NODEFAULTLIB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nodefaultlib-ignore-libraries?view=msvc-160) for each library you want to ignore.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The problem is solved now!

Comment: @KshitijKumar If my answer is useful, please help to mark as answers.Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.

Comment: Can't do that right now as my reputation is below 15! But still thanks for the ans.!